# How to prevent php foreach loop execute 2nd if statement when 1st if statement is executed?

Tags: php

```
<?php
foreach($abc as $row)
{
    $msg = "";
    if($row < 100 && $msg=="")
    {
        $msg="Dog";
    }
    
    if($row < 100 && $msg!="")
    {
        $msg=$msg."Cat";
    }
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

Let say it loop 3 data, the output is :

```
Cat Dog
Cat Dog
Cat Dog
```

How to make the output become :

```
Dog
Cat
Cat
```

I try to add flag to the code but still it is not working:

```
foreach($abc as $row)
{
    $msg = "";
    $flag=0;
    if($row < 100 && $msg=="" && $flag==0)
    {
        $msg="Dog";
        $flag=1;
    }
    
    if(row < 100 && $msg!="" && $flag==0)
    {
        $msg="Cat";
        $flag=1;
    }
}
```

How to prevent php foreach loop execute 2nd if statement when 1st if statement is executed?

Comment: Erm...... `else`?

Comment: Your code only echo one time, only Cat or Dog and only one time.

Comment: can't believe I didn't think of such a simple easy solution haha. Thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: @AbraCadaver, you have good eyes. Sorry for my silly mistake, I have correct it by adding `$msg=$msg."Cat";`

Comment: if you want print correct than add you echo $msg."<br>"; inside foreach loop. you will get your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a second `if` statement, you could use `elseif`.

```
elseif($row < 100 && $msg!="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```php
<?php
foreach($abc as $row)
{
    $msg = "";
    if($row < 100 && $msg=="")
    {
        $msg="Dog";
        break;
    }
    
    if($row < 100 && $msg!="")
    {
        $msg="Cat";
        break;
    }
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

Comment: Why the `break`s?  That exits the `foreach`.

Answer (score -1):

One problem is with your flow. Within your loop you are setting $msg="", then checking whether it is blank and setting $msg="Dog", then checking that $msg is not blank (which it is not, because you just set it to be "dog") and setting $msg="Cat".  It will always flow through those 3 steps.

More clarification might be needed on how you determine whether to output "dog" or "cat".